# Firebase Analytics for React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

Has anyone successfully run Firebase Analytics in React Native?
There is a [react-native-firebase-analytics](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-firebase-analytics) but it's installation documentation and support is poor. Also it does not install the plugin correctly. If you have been working on FB Analytics in React Native project, please share your tips.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using firebase sdk for web with react native? Analytics, offline capabilities etc, won't work with the apps if you use firebase sdk for web, check **react-native-firebase** which acts as a native bridge and enables all the functionalities of firebase for mobile. It has great documentation!

refer : [Firebase + React Native: Offline authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41894816/firebase-react-native-offline-authentication/43003350#43003350)

Edit:
I was able to get offline capabilities with in the app using **redux-persist** independent of the firebase sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with what you have said. I made that work by linking manually and run command

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app "package_name"
```

in react-native cli for enabling debug mode on firebase website.

And don't forget to put file `google-services.json` in your `android/app` folder.